# Facebook connect : How to force publish_actions?

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a website that use facebook connect, and I need the publish_action permission for each user, unless, user can't get access to my website.

But when a user register with Facebook connect, the *publish_action* permission can be skipped ; the request is separated from the read permissions.

This is an example of what I dont want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbz8g.png
Is there a way to ask to people to allow publish_action and read permissions in the same text box, without "skip" button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot require the publish permission to use your app.

Answer (score 0):

No. People must be able to login to your app without granting publishing permissions.